# When I "git push" git now says "Create pull request for ...". Why?

Tags: git, bitbucket, githooks, git-push

I am making changes to a project in a branch that, so far, is known to no one else but me.  However, starting recently, when I `git push` to this project, I now receive this as part of the response:

```
remote: Create pull request for <<my branch>>:
remote:   https://bitbucket.org/...
```

I have no idea why Git is giving me this message, which I have never seen before.

Even if I *delete* the remote branch (with "`git push origin :<<my branch>>`" I now *still* get this message! (I successfully **deleted** the branch on the remote, but the message remains)

Comment: Sounds like a server-side hook executing at bitbucket.org.

Comment: Well, *I* didn't do anything to cause such a thing, and since there are only two developers in question, can't imagine who/what would have done it.  What sort of "hook" might it be, and how can I determine if such a thing exists?

Comment: I also just saw this for the first time, bitbucket/atlassian must be doing some next level stuff to get people involved.

Comment: I saw the same. Apparently the push just happens normally and it seems you can ignore the output if you don't want to make a pull-request.

Comment: I haven't found a rationale for the change, but if it annoys you too consider up-voting [this bitbucket site issue](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/11409/revert-modify-create-pull-request-message).

Comment: It's pretty ridiculous, because it seems like to remove this I have to use one of Atlassian's other apps called "Stash"?

Comment: Nothing can be done from (y)our end. All we can do is to keep calm and follow this issue : https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/11409/revert-modify-create-pull-request-message

Answer (score 42):

*Note:* These messages can be disabled now. See [Jake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30948084/782822). Read along my answer for the technical explanation.

Everything that is prefixed by `remote:` has been sent by the [receiving script](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive)<sup>1</sup> on the server. Bitbucket probably wants to make it easier for you to create a pull request.

---

<sup>1</sup> Example of such a `post-receive` hook using `echo` to send a message to the user as explained in the link above. It will be called once all the pushed data is completely saved on the server:

> Both standard output and standard error output are forwarded to git send-pack on the other end, so you can simply echo messages for the user.

On the server:

```
git@example.com:~/stackoverflow.git/hooks$ cat post-receive 
#!/bin/bash

echo "This is an example of a git hook running at the server"
```

On the client:

```
$ git push git@example.com:stackoverflow.git master:master
Counting objects: 1, done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 187 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: This is an example of a git hook running at the server
To git@example.com:stackoverflow.git
   4751391..01882eb  master -> master
```

Comment: I know of no such "hooks" and can say with some certainty that "no one 'round here" has recently (or ever ...) built one.  I don't really know what you mean by "make it easier for you to create a pull request," since I have no such desire nor intention.  (This is 'my own, private, just to make sure I don't frobozz anything ...' branch.)

Comment: @MikeRobinson This hook probably is a generic hook set up by BitBucket. You probably have no control over these.

Answer (score 25):

I think TimWolla is right, but I just wanted to add [this post from Atlassian](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASHKB/How+Do+I+Disable+the+Remote+Create+Pull+Request+Message+When+Pushing+Changes), which clarifies Atlassian's policy:

> In Stash 3.3, a feature was added to display a message to users in the terminal with a link to create a pull request when a new branch or branch with no pull requests is pushed. This guide will explain how to turn this feature off.
>
> ```
> remote:
> remote: Create pull request for ABC-123-fix-bug:
> remote: http://localhost:7990/projects/PROJ/repos/REPO/compare/commits?sourceBranch=refs/heads/ABC-123-fix-bug
> remote:
> ```
>
> Currently this feature can only be turned on or off globally. [...]
>
> To turn this feature off, do the following:
>
> 1. Navigate to the 'Manage add-ons' section of the Stash admin screens
> 2. Select 'System' from the dropdown
> 3. Search for 'Bundled Hooks' expand it and its modules
> 4. Find the 'print-branch-links-hook' module, click Disable

Comment: I saw this, but it doesn't work for bitbucket users. There is an "Add-on management" option under manage accounts, but none of the other listed options.

Comment: It's okay... I see that it's a "fee-chur."  Now that I understand where it's coming from, I know how to ignore it.  :-)

Comment: Is it possible to edit the URL they return?  It would be nice to be able to include the destination branch "&dest=develop".  Right now it auto defaults to master. It causes problems when devs forget to switch the destination to develop branch.

Answer (score 19):

[TimWolla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/782822/timwolla) provided the full explanation, but here is how to get it fixed in the long term: Provide your feedback on [this support ticket](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/11409/revert-modify-create-pull-request-message) to show that you share the frustration expressed by other users over this issue.

**UPDATE:** As of 2016-09-27 this is no longer an issue and Atlassian has provided an [official response](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/11409/revert-modify-create-pull-request-message#comment-30615990) on the matter.

Here are the instructions for disabling these messages:

1. Log into BitBucket with your browser.
2. Click on your user icon on the top-right corner of the window.
3. Go to `BitBucket Settings`
4. Uncheck "Enable console messages."
5. Press the "Update" button below.

[image: Bitbucket Settings - Console Messages]

Comment: Any suggestions what to do if you do not have this option in Bitbucket or if the user is not one which you can login to Bitbucket with (jenkins user)?