# Git and Intelijj IDEA remote pull request on its own

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I got strange behaviour from my Intellij IDEA when I did `git push`. It suddenly create pull request into my bitbucket. Since I'm not an expert on git, I really don't know what happens.
Is anyone can help to explain what happen?
I put the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Remote repo is a fork from others?

Comment: @GenoChen Nope. It's my own repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46794246/6309), that seems to be expected.
It does not create the PR, but shows you how to create one should you need it.

> when you push a new branch up to a repo hosted in Bitbucket, it prints out (to the terminal screen) a URL that you can hit to create a PR from that branch you just pushed

If you manage your [own BitBucket server, you can turn that off](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/how-do-i-disable-the-remote-create-pull-request-message-when-pushing-changes-701268506.html).
But not for bitbucket.org. You can [only hide it](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/terminal-not-showing-create-pull-request-for-branch-http-link-to-bitbucket-repo-939922948.html) (as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30948084/6309)).

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. Because it's never happen before, so I got confused about it. Thanks for your explaination :D